# Review page warning - Is it logical?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug, review-audit

I was reviewing a post and suddenly a [2nd post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1476950/how-many-solutions-to-the-rational-equation), the answer by Andre Nicholas came up. I made the following comment: "If any polynomial of $n$ degree has more than $n$ zeroes, then it is called an identity."
 I just clicked on the "post comment" button. I did not even click the "I'm done" button.

But then [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/505840) came up.

My question is: **Was my comment so wrong? And that too I was going to upvote the answer after the comment. I didn't even press the "I'm done" button.** 
 Why did this happen? Can anybody help me out?

EDIT: After talking with quid, what I came to know is just what I was expecting. I request the mods to look into this issue and make sure that clicking the "add comment" button doesn't make you fail the test if the post is a good one.

Comment: It was a test-question to see if you review correctly. You failed this test. However, I would not worry much about it except if it happens frequently. There are some oddities in these test-scenarios. I do not think the content of your comment played a role, merely that you commented was the trigger. (That being said, I am not sure what the point of your comment is.)

Comment: @quid If the content of my comment is not judged, then I don't understand the reason for having such a test. It serves a very stereotypical role of a censor which judges you merely by your action and not by what your action means.

Comment: The reason for the test is to catch very poor reviewers that will fail the test repeatedly. A good reviewer will still fail some tests due to the test being simplistic, but it is inconsequential and thus a non-issue except if one makes a point of it.

Comment: @quid Thanks for your information.

Comment: See also [über meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188885/clicking-add-comment-fails-review-audit), and several linked questions. FYI, it's nothing moderators can do anything about, it's code, so requires a developer to be involved.

Comment: @BenMillwood I am more restrained on meta with closing, but it seems really the exact same concern and I voted to close as duplicate.